# How to retrieve data from jasin in $.ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

What is the problem of this code?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#butt").click(function() {     
              var name=$("#male").val();
              var age =$("#age").val();
              var edu=$("#education").val();
              var samy ={
                 "name":name,
                 "age":age,
                 "edu":edu       
              };
              $.ajax( {
                url:"email_ajax.php",
                data:"q="+samy, 
                type:"GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(res) {
               res = $.parseJSON(res);
                   $("#result").html(res);  
                }
            });
          });
        });
</script>  
</head>
<body>
    <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="text" name="male" id="male"><br/>
        <label for="Education">Education</label>
        <input type="text" name="education" id="education"><br/>
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br/>
        <input type="button" id="butt" name="butt">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

And in the next page

```
<?php
    $da=$_GET['q'];
    $data=json_decode($da);

    $x=$data['name'];
    $y=$data['age'];
    $z=$data['edu'];
    echo '<h4>'.$x.'</h4><br/>';
    echo '<h4>'.$y.'</h4><br/>';
    echo '<h4>'.$z.'</h4><br/>';
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: As far as I can see it's format is the main problem.

Comment: You are using `json_decode`, but you are not sending JSON to the server. You only try to concatenate an object with a string, which will result in something like `"q=[object Object]"`. If you really want to send JSON then you have to create JSON first. You can convert your object to JSON via `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `response` is not `json` as you used

```
dataType: "json",
```

in `$.ajax()`, your `response` is simple `html` remove the above line from your code or use

```
dataType: "html",
```

try this,

```
$.ajax({
    url:"email_ajax.php",
    data:"q="+samy, 
    type:"GET",
    success: function(res) {
        $("#result").html(res);  
    }
});
```

Comment: `samy` is an object, so perhaps that needs to be passed on its own, or converted to a string? (+1 for the question edits, good work).

Comment: how to convert this object in string in the second page